# How to connect the LBP statistical histogram to a feature vector

Tags: image-processing

To gain LBP histogram, we have to cut an image into some blocks. After we compute the histogram for each block, we connect the LBP histogram to a feature vector. My problem is how to write the program of the connection?

Comment: what do you mean by "we connect the LBP histogram to a feature vector."

Comment: Thank you for helping me correct！ I mean series connection，I want to use the LBP  feature  in  camshift program.